Stereo Digital Volume Control CS3310
I want to replace a component of my Audio Card, the Stereo Digital Volume Control CS3310.
I have two questions :

What type of components is it. Is it a micro controller, a microprocessor, or something else ?
Somebody told me that i cannot replace it because if it is a micro controller or microprocessor will have its own firmware and if i replace it with a new one, the card will be useless. Is this the true with micro controllers and microprocessors ?

This card is a PCI audio card snaps onto the motherboard of my PC (Windows OS)
The datasheet of this component is here :
https://d3uzseaevmutz1.cloudfront.net/pubs/proDatasheet/CS3310_F1.pdf

What is the reason for wanting to replace the CS3310? E.g. have you confirmed the CS3310 is faulty?


It's a digital volume control IC. It is controlled entirely by external signals. It has no internal nonvolatile storage.

Yes, this is generally true of microcontrollers (but not microprocessors, which usually have their programming stored in separate devices). This does not apply to the CS3310.


